# More MenuItems shown than needed after rotation in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have an app (for 4.0 and above) which has couple of `MenuItem`s in the `ActionBar` (one with 'always' and the rest with 'ifRoom' or 'never' property).

So the issue goes like this...
If I launch the app in landscape mode, the `ActionBar` looks like the following:
[image: launched in landscape mode]

When I rotate to landscape from portrait, the `ActionBar` looks like this:
[image: landscape from portrait]

As you can see, more icons appear than they should be, i.e no space is left for title bar and the tabs menu (Navigation Menu). Actually, the 4 items are shown in the portrait mode (it's a split ActionBar) and it seems that the Android doesn't realise that there's no SplitActionBar there anymore.

Please suggest what I can do to fix this? :)

---

### Edit

My menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/share"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_viewToggle"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_view_as_grid"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/switch_view"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_upload"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_upload"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/upload"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_newFolder"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_new_folder"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/create_folder"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_multiselect"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_select_all"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/selection_mode"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/refresh"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Can you show us your layout(s) xml for the menu items?

Comment: @shkschneider Thanks. I have now added that in my question. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you take care of each menu item visibility in your menu.xml file, check out the xml ShowAsAction attribute.

here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/SOME_MENU_ITEM"
    android:icon="@drawable/SOME_ICON"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" | "collapseActionView"
    android:title="SOME_TITLE"/>
.
.
```

Comment: I have added my menu.xml in my question. Please check.

Comment: for each menu item you don't want to show in your action bar, set `android:showAsAction="never"`

Comment: You are setting `ifRoom` to every menu item you have defined, which means that the more space you have on screen the more items will show in your action bar, set those you don't want to show up in your action bar to `android:showAsAction="never"`

Comment: It seems I wasn't clear in my description. The problem I was having was that no space was left for the title and navigation menu(?). The main idea is to show as many items as possible but no more than they are possible.

Answer (score 0):

One of the important attribute xml for menu items is,
android:showAsAction ,that defines the visibility of the action item.
From your code it is evident that if there is room in action bar it'll display it.
So if you don't want it to appear specify android:showAsAction value as never so that whatever the orientation is it'll appear only in the overflow menu.

Comment: It seems I wasn't clear in my description. The problem I was having was that no space was left for the title and navigation menu(?) [see image 1 and 2]. The main idea is to show as many items as possible but no more than they are possible, and it's not happening.